# click on overlapping child windows

Tags: windows, click, overlap, childwindow

I have an unusual problem for which I can't find a solution via searches. I have a form-type screen consisting of text, checkboxes, buttons, etc. I need to temporarily pop up a virtual keyboard for input (touchscreen). This works fine, except that, invariably, if there is a selectable item *underneath* a 'key', pressing the 'key' actually generates a click event on the underlying element. This seems counter-intuitive to me. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer this without knowing how your form and virtual keyboard are implemented. You should post some example code, possibly reducing it to the simplest test case you can think of. (E.g. a form with nothing but two buttons overlapping in the way you describe.)

Comment: My guess is the latter uses some sort of low-level event handling and doesn't "consume" the click event to prevent it being handled by an occluded control; but without code it's just a guess.